# Two Codeigniter running in same server. Route to subfoler CI

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I have 2 codeigniters running in the same server. Let's call CI_A and CI_B.

The folder structure is the following:

```
CI_A/
 ../application
 ../system
 ../admin/     <-- this is my CI_B
    ../application
    ../system
```

When I access to "www.example.com" I'm working with CI_A.
When I access to "www.example.com/admin" I'm working with CI_B. (I had to modify route.php in CI_A for make it work).

But I want to access to a another controller in CI_B using the url "www.example.com/api" and I don't know how.

Comment: You can reach it over `www.example.com/admin/api`. No other way. Also in `.htaccess` allow reading admin directory like `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to edit the index.php file located in the main htdocs folder and then do something like this (I believe):

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'api') !=== false || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'admin') !=== false){
    $application_folder = 'PATH TO B';
} elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'admin') !=== false){
    $application_folder = 'PATH TO A';
}
```

This assumes you have a single htdocs managing it all - else you may need to just manually edit the index.php file in each folder to point the application_folder path to the correct location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this is not what I'm looking for. I want to access to the entire CI_B(including system folder) under admin folder. I'm stuck with that, looks like  CI does not support to access directly to a server folder.

Comment: Can you not just add in the System path under the PATH TO A bit instead? Run 2x different system sets? I can update the answer if that would help.